# What is the difference between token and span (a slice from a doc) in spaCy?

Tags: python, nlp, token, spacy

I would like to know what is the difference between **token** and **span** in **spaCy**.

Also what is the main reason when we have to work with span? Why can't we simply use token to do any NLP? Specially when we use **spaCy matcher**?

**Brief Background**:
My problem came up when I wanted to get index of span (its exact index in string doc not its ordered index in spaCy doc) after using **spaCy matcher** which returns '*match_id*', '*start*' and '*end*', and so I could get span out of this information, not a token.
Then I needed to create a training_data which requires exact index of word in a sentence. If I had access to token, I could simply use token.idx but span does not have that! So I have to write extra codes to find the index of word (which is the same as span) in its sentence!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### `Token` vs `Span`

From spaCy's documentation, a [`Token`](https://spacy.io/api/token) represents a single word, punctuation symbol, whitespace, etc. from a document, while a [`Span`](https://spacy.io/api/span) is a slice from the document. In other words, a `Span` is an ordered sequence of `Token`s.

### Why `Span`s?

spaCy's `Matcher` gives a `Span`-level information rather than `Token`-level, because it allows a sequence of `Token`s to be matched. In the same way that a `Span` can be composed of just 1 `Token`, this isn't necessarily the case.

Consider the following example. Where we match for the `Token` `"hello"` on its own, the `Token` `"world"` on its own, and the `Span` composed of the `Token`s `"hello"` & `"world"`.

```py
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load("en")
>>> from spacy.matcher import Matcher
>>> matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
>>> matcher.add(1, None, [{"LOWER": "hello"}])
>>> matcher.add(2, None, [{"LOWER": "world"}])
>>> matcher.add(3, None, [{"LOWER": "hello"}, {"LOWER": "world"}])
```

For `"Hello world!"` all of these patterns match:

```py
>>> document = nlp("Hello world!")
>>> [(token.idx, token) for token in document]
[(0, Hello), (6, world), (11, !)]
>>> matcher(document)
[(1, 0, 1), (3, 0, 2), (2, 1, 2)]
```

However, the 3rd pattern doesn't match for `"Hello, world!"`, since `"Hello"` & `"world"` aren't contiguous `Token`s (because of the `","` `Token`), so they don't form a `Span`:

```py
>>> document = nlp("Hello, world!")
>>> [(token.idx, token) for token in document]
[(0, Hello), (5, ,), (7, world), (12, !)]
>>> matcher(document)
[(1, 0, 1), (2, 2, 3)]
```

### Accessing `Token`s from `Span`s

Despite this, you should be able to get `Token`-level information from the span by iterating over the `Span`, the same way you could iterate over `Token`s in a `Doc`.

```py
>>> document = nlp("Hello, world!")
>>> span, type(span)
(Hello, world, <class 'spacy.tokens.span.Span'>)
>>> [(token.idx, token, type(token)) for token in span]
[(0, Hello, <class 'spacy.tokens.token.Token'>), (5, ,, <class 'spacy.tokens.token.Token'>), (7, world, <class 'spacy.tokens.token.Token'>)]
```

Comment: Thank you, great explaination

Comment: Note idx is the span index in the document. I prefer the token/word index which is token.i 
 per: https://spacy.io/api/token

Answer (score 3):

You can access the tokens within a span just like it's a list:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
text = "This is a sentence."
doc = nlp(text)
span = doc[2:4]
span_char_start = span[0].idx
span_char_end = span[-1].idx + len(span[-1].text)
assert text[span_char_start:span_char_end] == "a sentence"
```